# Sync Records With Default Values in Pivot Tables, Call to undefined method syncWithPivotDefaults()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I just upgraded `laravel 7` to `laravel 8.30.1` and
I am trying to add the default value of pivot column `object_model` of `term_relationships` table using the newly introduced method `[syncWithPivotDefaults][1]()` of `laravel 8.2`

### ERROR

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::syncWithPivotDefaults()
```

#### Table structure of `term_relationships` table

```
ID
object_id
term_id
object_model
created_at
updated_at
```

#### Code in PostController

```php
$cat_ids = [1,2,3];
$post->categories()->syncWithPivotDefaults($cat_ids, ['object_model', 'App/Post']);
```

#### Relationship In Post Model

```php
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Term::class, 'term_relationships', 'object_id', 'term_id')
                  ->where('taxonomy', 'category')
                  ->withTimestamps();          
  }
```

Comment: that method doesn't exist under that name ... it is `syncWithPivotValues` ... and it should be taking an associative array most likely

Comment: Please see this article https://laravel-news.com/laravel-8-20-0

Comment: the method is now `syncWithPivotValues` ... in case you are not following the chnages  https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/49b3ce098d8a612797b195c4e3774b1e00c604c8#diff-5603d4d15ca47b196de2c3f2c70590b20cb523a393228fc7f294a2c6a54c443c

Comment: laravel news might be reporting something but they were premature on it and usually when a PR comes in after it is merged the core team will make adjustments ... this is the **official** change log: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/CHANGELOG-8.x.md#v8200-2020-12-22

Answer (score 0):

The correct method name is `syncWithPivotValues()`. The method-name had been changed from the PR before release. It is best to follow the offical change log so you know the final change: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/CHANGELOG-8.x.md#v8200-2020-12-22

More information on how to use this method is in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

> If you would like to insert the same intermediate table values with each of the synced model IDs, you may use the syncWithPivotValues method:
>
> ```
> $user->roles()->syncWithPivotValues([1, 2, 3], ['active' => true]);
> ```